# how to Display data in matrix with with more than 4 decimals

Tags: matlab, number-formatting

He,

My question is about this matlab 
output:

```
>>model3.Mu

ans =

0.7677    -1.1755   -0.8956

-0.0100    0.0883    0.0235

0.0001    -0.0010   -0.0003

-0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
```

How to display this data in a 4x3 matrix with more than 4 decimals?

Answer (score 8):

type at the matlab prompt:

```
>> help format
```

I think what you want to do is issue the command "FORMAT LONG" before you execute your script.

You can also print the matrix out to arbitrary precision using fprintf in a loop.

Comment: `format long g` just to ensure you don't get scientific  notation

Comment: I'm shocked Matlab doesn't give you the option to set the exact number of decimal figures to display. "long" i too long and "short" is too short for my needs...