# How to display with n decimal places in Matlab

Tags: matlab, number-formatting

I was wondering how to use command to set up displaying with n decimal places in Matlab?

Must n be restricted to some predetermined numbers? Or one can just specify any for n?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Possible duplicates: [how to Display data in matrix with with more than 4 decimals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311520/how-to-display-data-in-matrix-with-with-more-than-4-decimals), [Is it possible to show numbers in non-engineering format in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999205/is-it-possible-to-show-numbers-in-non-engineering-format-in-matlab). Short answer: look into the [FORMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/format.html) command.

Answer (score 10):

You can convert a number to a string with *n* decimal places using the [SPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) command:

```
>> x = 1.23;
>> sprintf('%0.6f', x)

ans =

1.230000

>> x = 1.23456789;
>> sprintf('%0.6f', x)

ans =

1.234568
```

Comment: Thanks! But I just want it to be numeric not string.

Comment: @Tim: I'm not sure what you mean by wanting it to be numeric. It is numeric! If you want to round a number to the sixth decimal place you could do `round(x*10^6)/10^6`.

Comment: For rounding numbers, there are several variants of @b3's code in the file exchange: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21121-round-to-specified-digits-place http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4261-round2 http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6077-round2

Answer (score 4):

This site might help you out with all of that:

http://herz-fischler.ca/MATLAB/section15.html

Answer (score -2):

i use like tim say `sprintf('%0.6f', x)`, it's a string then i change it to number by using command `str2double(x)`.

Comment: you are increasing computation time by 2 times