# Display multiple values in one line

Tags: matlab, number-formatting, output-formatting

I'm new to MATLAB. I have two values `x` and `y`. Both of them contain values with unknown accuracy. The problem: How could I display them both in one row with 2 digits after comma? Like:

```
x<tabulation or stack of spaces>y<then goes new line>
```

### Example

#### RAW data

```
  0,324352           0,75234
  1,563              3,4556
```

#### Expected output

```
0,34                0,75
1,56                3,45
```

Upd: for one value it works well

```
disp('x=' num2str(x,3));
```

Purpose is: display TWO values on one row with the new line symbol

Comment: This Q&A might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149348/how-to-display-with-n-decimal-places-in-matlab?rq=1

Comment: What about `num2str([x,y],3)`?

Comment: Thanks, that gave me thought on right answer

Comment: look at [`sprintf`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) for an output to a string or [`fprintf`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) for an output directly into the console or into a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The answer is:

```
disp(num2str([x y],3));
```

The 3 value means - max.quanity of symbols after comma including it(am I wrong? just thoughts)

#### Another Idea:

Somehow represent X and Y as array values and then display them.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use others' comments as your answer about which you have obviously doubts.

Comment: I thanked user for correct answer, but  it wasn't good enough completed.

Comment: How your answer is different (good enough complete) from the one line comment by @Daniel ?